# How to copy/move object from one bucket to another in AWS S3 in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

Recently I have migrated my code from .NetFramework to .NetCore 3.1.
While doing this I got stuck in a place where **MoveFolder** functionality handled.

Earlier the code was like below.

```
    public void MoveS3Folder(string sourceBucket, string targetBucket, string sourceFolder, string targetFolder)
    {
        sourceFolder = sourceFolder.Replace('/', '\\');
        targetFolder = targetFolder.Replace('/', '\\');
        using (var client = AwsObjectCreator.GetAmzonS3())
        {
            var source = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, sourceBucket, sourceFolder);
            S3DirectoryInfo target = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, targetBucket, targetFolder);

            if (!target.Exists)
            {
                target.Create();
            }

            try
            {
                source.MoveTo(target);
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                if (e.Message.Equals("File already exists", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    target = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, targetBucket, targetFolder + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss"));
                    target.Create();
                    source.MoveTo(target);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Since, earlier we were using **AWSSDK.S3** Sdk package which has **S3DirectoryInfo** class, with the help of this we had achieved the goal.

Now, I would be looking for a similar solution w.r.t **AWSSDKCore.S3**.

**Things I have tried so far:**

1. https://www.derpturkey.com/copy-a-folder-in-amazons3-using-the-c-api/
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingNetSDK.html

I understood the concept of copying data from the above articles but not worked on my end.

**Error I am getting** -  “The specified key does not exist”

It will be appreciable, if anyone could help !

Comment: " but not worked on my end." - What's not working?  Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: @PhilipPittle Apologies for replying late and thanks for highlighting. the error i am getting is “The specified key does not exist”. I hope this would help !

Comment: Where do you get that error? What's the *full* exception text? You can't copy a non-existent file after all.

Comment: Are you using an actual file key? Or trying to move all items in a "folder'? Cloud storage solutions have no folders - such hierarchical structures simply don't scale when you have millions of items in a bucket. They *emulate* folders by treating a special character in the key as a "folder" separator, and allowing you to search for files using a specific prefix. If you have a file named `a/b1/c1`, `a/b1/c2`, `a/b2/c2` etc, when you "list" the folder `a/b1` you're actually searching for every file with a key that starts with `a/b1`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **var client = AwsObjectCreator.GetAmzonS3()** ----Wrong way
Create the client like this

```
 IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
```